# Greatest integer less than or equal to $x^*$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If it is said that $x^*$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x^*$, and I found $x^*=7.71$, then will I take $x^*=7$?

I am confused as usually we take $8$ if it is $7.71$.

Comment: I guess some of your $x^*$ should have been just $x$.

Comment: @celtschk Actually the idea is to replace the old value of $x^*$ by new value of $x^*$ .

Comment: We usually write $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, so $\lfloor 7.71 \rfloor = 7$ while $\lfloor 8 \rfloor = 8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "greatest integer less than or equal", you always round down.

Ordinary rounding is different. It rounds to the **closest** integer, which could be up or down.

In fact, they are related by $$\operatorname{ordinaryRound}(x)=\operatorname{roundDown}(x+\tfrac12)$$